# Selecting categories and articles

Tags: php, mysql

I have a question regarding MySQL. (&Php)

I have 3 tables:

```
Articles (id, title, content)
Articles_category (id,article_id,category_id,main,cposition)
Categories (id,title,content)
```

main - 0/1 (main category or not).
cposition - position on breadcrumbs -  1,2,3,... (or 0 - so it wont appear on breadcrumbs at all).

now, lets say i have 3 levels:

```
Home -> Articles -> News & Politics.
```

And I'm now going to - Articles.

I want Articles category to list all articles with their categories.

That means ->

```
Articles.

News & Politics 
 [article1]
 [article2]
Military 
 [article1]
 [article2]
-- (articles that their main category is Articles)
 [article1]
 [article2]
 [article3]
```

How do i fetch this data and parse it one query (and if not possible in one, whats the best way to do it efficiently?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try like

```
select c.title, a.title from Articles a 
left join 
Articles_category b
on a.id=b.article_id
left join
Categories c
on c.id = b.category_id
order by b.main, c.id, b.cposition
```

Comment: Please explain - I tried it and I didnt get any data. 
I have an example.
article id = 5 thats has categories: 6,7,8 and 7 is its main.

Comment: Actually I think it works - can you just explain the query so i'll learn from it? thanks!

Comment: i joined the tables , with the foreign fields, and so i get the articles with there categories, after that i order the results by the main(to get what is not main , after the main category) after that order by category_id and last order by cposition (in the same category)

Comment: It 90% done - It works, but I want it pull the article with its main category id. (that means, that if the article's main category isnt the one that pulled him in the query, i want the it would select also its main category id (and possibly titles))

Comment: try to add the field main to query like : 'select c.title, a.title , b.main .......' its help to you ?

Comment: No, but i solved it:
just added - LEFT JOIN Articles_category ac1
ON ac1.main = 1 AND a.id = ac1.article_id 
Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

why not put the category_id in the article table?

Comment: Because I want each article to have multiple categories. thats why i've created articles_category table, to link between articles to their categories.